# If prepend text missing then add text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to find a way to prepend our domain name if it is missing or was not typed in.

Below is the code for my form. For the username I would like it to check if domainname\ is there, and if so proceed as normal, but if domainname\is not there, than add it. The end results would be domainname\username. I tried doing $('DOMAIN\').val() + before the username, but that did not work.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Web Proxy request to fetch the configuration
        ajaxWrapper({ url: 'Home/Configuration', dataType: 'xml', success: configSuccess });

        $('form').submit(function () {
            var username = $('#username').val(),
                password = $('#password').val();

            clearMessage();

            if (!username || !password) {
                showMessage('Enter a username and a password');
                return false;
            }

            // Web Proxy request to log the user on
            ajaxWrapper({
                url: 'PostCredentialsAuth/Login',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: loginSuccess,
                error: loginError,
                data: { username: username, password: password }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

```html
<form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter credentials</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="username">User name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="login-button" name="login-button" value="Log On" />
    </form>
```

Comment: just miss   }); at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple **[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** check and possible string concatenation will do the trick:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      
  // Web Proxy request to fetch the configuration
  ajaxWrapper({ url: 'Home/Configuration', dataType: 'xml', success: configSuccess });

  $('form').submit(function () {
    var username = $('#username').val(),
    password = $('#password').val();

    clearMessage();

    if (!username || !password) {
      showMessage('Enter a username and a password');
      return false;
    }

    // Ensure the user name is correct...
    // If the username has the domain string at position 0, then
    // the username is correct and just use it as normal, but if
    // not, username needs to have the domain prepended.
    // Because of the backslashes in the strings, they need to be 
    // escaped with "\\"
    username = username.indexOf("domain\\") === 0 ? username : "domain\\" + username;

    // Web Proxy request to log the user on
    ajaxWrapper({
      url: 'PostCredentialsAuth/Login',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: loginSuccess,
      error: loginError,
      data: { username: username, password: password }
    });

    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enter credentials</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="username">User name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" id="login-button" name="login-button" value="Log On" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Now as a 2nd question, is there a way to add a timeout that will log you out after x minutes. There is a log off button that gets show after you login. So maybe like a function to select that log off function after x minutes?

Comment: @AnthonyZepeda There is, but you should post that as a separate question so that we can answer there and the community can benefit from it. Also, don't forget to up vote my answer as well. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a new question. Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889532/logon-timeout-settings I did select he upvote, but looks like I need 15 reputation for it to show up.